# Move an Bitmap half off the screen

Tags: android

I am drawing a Revolving Bitmap image in the shape of a donut. Now i want to move the Donut to the bottom of the screen such that the center of the Bitmap image is at the bottom center of the screen. How can i do this ? I want this so only half of the donut is visible to the user, and the rest half is off the screen.

===========================

I am drawing an Bitmap into a custom View class. I want to  calculate the height and width of the screen, and then move the center of the view to y=0 and x=width/2. How can i do this ? This is the code for the onSizeChanged for my custom view

```
  */
    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

        // method called multiple times but initialized just once
        if (wheelHeight == 0 || wheelWidth == 0) {
            wheelHeight = h;
            wheelWidth = w;
            // resize the image
            Matrix resize = new Matrix();
            resize.postScale((float)0.75, (float)0.75);
            imageScaled = Bitmap.createBitmap(imageOriginal, 0, 0, imageOriginal.getWidth(),
                    imageOriginal.getHeight(), resize, false);
            // translate the matrix to the image view's center
            float translateX = wheelWidth / 2 - imageScaled.getWidth() / 2;
            float translateY = wheelHeight / 2 - imageScaled.getHeight() / 2;
            matrix.postTranslate(translateX, translateY);
            WheelMenu.this.setImageBitmap(imageScaled);
            WheelMenu.this.setImageMatrix(matrix);






        }
    }
```

I want to move the view to the half of the screen, and secondly i want to set the size of the view to the size of scaled bitmap ?

Kind Regards

Comment: you can achieve it through animations..

Comment: Did you try adding margins to the top?

Comment: The bitmap is created at runtime. I want to move the Bitmap to a new set of corrdinates